# inmobi ads not opening

Tags: android, inmobi

I have incorporated inmobi ads in my android app.in my app i can see the ad from inmobi when i open the app. but when i click on the ad nothing happens. and i checked ddms which tells me this:

```
ActivityNotFoundException. no activity found to handle the intent
```

The following is my code snippet

```
imAdView = new IMAdView(this, IMAdView.INMOBI_AD_UNIT_320X50,"xxxxxxx(my app id kept secret)");
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.adview);
    layout.addView(imAdView);
    imAdView.setIMAdRequest(adRequest);
    imAdView.loadNewAd();
```

do i need to import anything more??

Answer (score 1):

I work for InMobi.  That all looks ok, but it might be worth following our latest tutorial - http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=Android